# Aws Iot limitation, Maximum number of policies that can be attached to a certificate or Amazon

Tags: aws-iot

If i have many devices, and cognito accounts to use the topics of devices with the m-device to n-cognito-account.
The limitation of policy have the max policy document size and maximum number of policies that can be attached.

For example:
There has 2 device and 2 user

For current, design :

Device policy -> data/${clinet_id}

Cognito users both need attach policy -> data/${device_clinet_id1} and data/${device_clinet_id2}
(Policy has limitation which didn't work when number of device is too large.)

Is there something method that i can use refs array variable of policy from cognito such as iot things attrs with array type or refs from other storage service.